Creating a typed wrapper around MUI's styled() utility using TypeScript
I want to add a suffix to every generated class name, so I'm passing the label option to styled like so:
const Root = styled(MyComponent, {
    label: 'my-suffix',
})(() => ({
 // ...
}));

This isn't practical for maintainability and reusability because I have hundreds of styled components across many files, so I created a wrapper around styled():
import { styled as muiStyled } from '@mui/material/styles';

export const styled = (component, options) => (styles) =>
  muiStyled(component, {
    ...options,
    label: 'my-suffix',
  })(styles);

However, my project is using TypeScript, so I need to add the correct types for component, options, and styles.
I tried to follow this type definition file to add types to my wrapper:
export const styled =
    <
        MUIStyledCommonProps extends object,
        C extends React.ComponentClass<React.ComponentProps<C>>,
        ForwardedProps extends keyof React.ComponentProps<C> = keyof React.ComponentProps<C>,
        Theme extends object = DefaultTheme,
    >(
        component: C,
        options: FilteringStyledOptions<React.ComponentProps<C>, ForwardedProps>,
    ) =>
    (
        styles: CreateStyledComponent<
            Pick<PropsOf<C>, ForwardedProps> & MUIStyledCommonProps,
            object,
            {
                ref?: React.Ref<InstanceType<C>>;
            },
            Theme
        >,
    ) =>
        muiStyled(component, {
            ...options,
            label: 'my-suffix',
        })(styles);

But it's not correct.
